# Application to create flash demo of a website

Tags: flash

I'm looking for some software to create a flash demo 'tour' of a website I've created.  FOS would be preferred but commercial is ok so long as not too expensive (I'm probably going to use this just the once).

Ideally something programmable to I can edit the demo and insert text, overlays etc.  I'm also not interested in adding sound.

Recommendations?

Comment: You know, the problem with marking this down for being off topic is that when I posted it back in 09 it was perfectly in keeping with how SO functioned then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not opensource but it is free and works on Windows and Linux

Wink from [Debugmode.com](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) is pretty good

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Captivate can record actions which can be edited.
It outputs a flash movie.

Answer (score 1):

Captivate by Adobe is pretty much the standard app that people in business use but that's pretty expensive.

I have had good experience with Wondershare products so I'd expect this one to be pretty good (only $100):

http://www.sameshow.com/democreator/article/software-demo-making.html

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these are free, but they're 
not outrageously expensive, either.

Tanida Demo Builder
http://www.demo-builder.com/

TechSmith Camtasia Studio
http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/features/win/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, ScreenFlow is an absolutely fantastic program. It costs $99, but is very professional and well worth the money.

http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm